# Compare Text From Excel Worksheet to HTML Table Value

Tags: html, excel, vba, compare

I am scraping a website's HTML table for a specific value, and if this value matches a cell in the Excel workbook, I want it to perform a specific action. I will display my code and then explain the issue below:

```
    With HTMLDoc
        Application.wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        .getElementsByName("11.1.1.13.7.4.1.11.0.1.0")(0).Click
        Application.wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
        '.querySelector("[title='New Note']").Click
        .getElementsByClassName("navSmallCenterUp")(1).Click
        
        
        '1st Asset
         Application.wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
                         
         If Not .getElementsByName("7.25.0.0.0.0.2.9.0.0.1.2.3.1.5.3.3.0.1.3.1.5.0.0.1.2.9.3.1.9.2.1.3.1.0.1.1.1.30.1.30.1.4.1")(0) Is Nothing Then
            .getElementsByName("7.25.0.0.0.0.2.9.0.0.1.2.3.1.5.3.3.0.1.3.1.5.0.0.1.2.9.3.1.9.2.1.3.1.0.1.1.1.30.1.30.1.4.1")(0).Value = mainSheet.Range("E19").Value
            Application.wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
            .getElementsByClassName("panelButton")(2).Click
            Application.wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
            .getElementsByClassName("rightAlign")(1).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
        Else
            .getElementsByName("7.25.0.0.0.0.2.3.0.0.1.2.0.3.0.1.5.3.3.0.1.3.1.5.0.0.1.2.9.3.1.9.2.1.3.1.0.1.1.1.30.1.30.1.4.1")(0).Value = mainSheet.Range("E19").Value
            Application.wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
            .getElementsByClassName("panelButton")(2).Click
            Application.wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
            .getElementsByClassName("rightAlign")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
        End If
        
        Set Table = .getElementsByClassName("alternatingRowColor")
        Set tRows = Table(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
        
        For Each r In tRows
            Set tCells = r.getElementsByTagName("td")
            
            For Each c In tCells
                If c.innerText = mainSheet.Range("E19").Value Then
                    MsgBox (c.innerText)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

So to start off, `.getElementsByName("7.25.0.0.0.0.2.3.0.0.1.2.0.3.0.1.5.3.3.0.1.3.1.5.0.0.1.2.9.3.1.9.2.1.3.1.0.1.1.1.30.1.30.1.4.1")(0).Value = mainSheet.Range("E19").Value`
enters in the value of "E19" to a specific field of the website (in this case, the value is 95520), and this works perfectly. I then want to find where in the table this has been entered, so I am looping through the table until it is found:

```
For Each r In tRows
            Set tCells = r.getElementsByTagName("td")

            For Each c In tCells
                If c.innerText = mainSheet.Range("E19").Value Then
                    MsgBox (c.innerText)
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

The problem is, when I am comparing the innertext of the table to the cell in the worksheet, it does not match. When I replace `If c.innerText = mainSheet.Range("E19").Value Then` with `If c.innerText = 95520 Then` it works perfectly. Again, the value of is `mainSheet.Range("E19")` 95520. I am very confused, and if someone could point me in the right direction, that would be awesome!

Comment: Is there a public webpage you are using for this? Is html tag relevant to this?

Comment: I am working on a project for work, and it involves our private intranet webpages.

Comment: I think you compare a `String` and a `Long`. Try this: `If c.innerText = CStr(mainSheet.Range("E19").Value) Then`. That was the solution on the same issue for me a few days ago. Another hint. Don't use a loop over all cells, use `Range.Find()`. That is faster https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-find/